# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on multiple file upload with node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, asyncfileupload

I am trying to upload multiple files on ftp using node.js. My uploading start successfully and i see the file uploaded in the server location, but after some time not receiving the success message, at browser end i am getting this error "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): but in server my files are still uploading on ftp.

Here is the upload log for the process:

```
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1572528
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1637949
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1703388
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1768865
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1834167
PUT /user/album/deliverAudio - - ms - -   
               // as soon as this line execute I get EMPTY_RESPONSE_ERROR in browser
uploaded Audio >>1 >>1899552
```

Below is the partial code for the process:

```
sync.map(req.body.tracks, function(track, callback) {
    var data = '';
    var filename = '';
    var readableAudioStream = fs.createReadStream(track.trackpath.track_path);
    c.put(readableAudioStream,track.filename, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      callback(null);
    });
    readableAudioStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
      console.log('uploaded Audio >>'+track.track_no+' >>'+data.length);
    });
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log('audio error');
  console.log(err);
  done(err);
});
```

Comment: What is `c.put()`? If it's uploading the data from the stream to some other place and calling its callback when it's done, you probably shouldn't have a `data` event handler there.

Comment: in c.put c is my ftp object which is node-ftp and put is its method.

Comment: even after removing data event handler I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably giving a NULL/undefined response to the HTTP request.  Try sending an actual payload in the response.

Try

```
c.put(readableAudioStream,track.filename, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  callback(null, { success: true }); // Give an actual payload response from the completion of the upload
});
```

Then later, handle the results from the request:

```
function (err, results) {
   if (err) res.send(500, err);
   res.json(results);
}
```

Comment: at where I have to put it?

Comment: I have one more step after this step in Async.waterfall, so what should I pass?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I can answer that without full context, but my point is that you should try sending an actual payload response rather than undefined/null.  Just send anything and I'm thinking that might fix it.  If you're handling the `results` param in the next step, it should get the `{ success: true }` object and send that with `res.json(results)`.